# Write arbitrary Eigen object to row-major plain storage

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am writing a module to write data to a file which uses by convention only row-major storage. I would like my function to be able to allow both column-major and row-major Eigen objects as input.

Currently I first use Eigen to copy a column-major object to a row-major object, before I write. My code works well for most cases, but for `Eigen::VectorXi` compiling fails with an assertion that I don't understand. *How do I solve this?* Can I avoid creating many cases?

The code (writing is mimicked by outputting a `std::vector`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

template <class T, int Rows, int Cols, int Options, int MaxRows, int MaxCols>
std::vector<T> write(const Eigen::Matrix<T,Rows,Cols,Options,MaxRows,MaxCols>& matrix)
{
    std::vector<T> data(static_cast<size_t>(matrix.size()));

    if (matrix.IsRowMajor) {
        std::copy(matrix.data(), matrix.data()+matrix.size(), data.begin());
        return data;
    } else {
        Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Eigen::RowMajor, MaxRows, MaxCols> tmp = matrix;
        return write(tmp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::VectorXi matrix = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(10, 0, 9);

    std::vector<int> output = write(matrix);
}
```

The compilation error:

```
In file included from test.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:457:
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:903:7: error: static_assert failed "INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS"
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/StaticAssert.h:33:40: note: expanded from macro 'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT'
    #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);
                                       ^             ~
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:535:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1>
      >::_check_template_params' requested here
      _check_template_params();
      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:377:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1>
      >::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >' requested here
      : Base(other.derived())
        ^
test.cpp:14:79: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >' requested here
        Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Eigen::RowMajor, MaxRows, MaxCols> tmp = matrix;
                                                                              ^
test.cpp:23:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'write<int, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>' requested here
    std::vector<int> output = write(matrix);
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Understanding the static assertion**

Unfortunately the assertion is really not self-explanatory and the only thing you can get from it is the hint, that something is wrong with your template parameters. If we look into [Eigen's source code](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/PlainObjectBase_8h_source.html) we find the following beginning on line 903:

```
EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
                        && EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxColsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==0)
                        && ((RowsAtCompileTime == Dynamic) || (RowsAtCompileTime >= 0))
                        && ((ColsAtCompileTime == Dynamic) || (ColsAtCompileTime >= 0))
                        && ((MaxRowsAtCompileTime == Dynamic) || (MaxRowsAtCompileTime >= 0))
                        && ((MaxColsAtCompileTime == Dynamic) || (MaxColsAtCompileTime >= 0))
                        && (MaxRowsAtCompileTime == RowsAtCompileTime || RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic)
                        && (MaxColsAtCompileTime == ColsAtCompileTime || ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic)
                        && (Options & (DontAlign|RowMajor)) == Options),
        INVALID_MATRIX_TEMPLATE_PARAMETERS)
```

Even though the compiler indicates that

```
EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
```

causes the error, the following line really does:

```
EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxColsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==0)
```

**Understanding what triggers the assertion**

You provide `Eigen::VectorXi` as an input for `write`. `Eigen::VectorXi` is really just a typedef for

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::ColMajor, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>
```

Therefore the line

```
Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Eigen::RowMajor, MaxRows, MaxCols> tmp = matrix;
```

in `write` expands to

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::RowMajor, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> tmp = matrix;
```

which triggers the assertion, since a matrix with `MaxColsAtCompileTime==1` and `MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=1` must not be `RowMajor`.

**Solve your problem**

The problem now is that even though you can check if your input matrix is a vector, row-major or column-major, you cannot declare

```
Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Eigen::RowMajor, MaxRows, MaxCols>
```

if it is no legal to do so at compile-time (and it isn't due to the static assertion).

You have the following options to make your code work:

**1. `if constexpr` (C++17)**

C++17 offers a way for detecting at compile-time if a certain conditional branch will be taken or not. The downside of this approach (beside the requirement for a C++17 compiler) is that you can only test for constant expressions.

In the concrete example this looks like this:

```
template <class T, int Rows, int Cols, int Options, int MaxRows, int MaxCols>
std::vector<T> write(const Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Options, MaxRows, MaxCols>& matrix)
{
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Options, MaxRows, MaxCols> MatrixType;
  std::vector<T> data(static_cast<size_t>(matrix.size()));

  if constexpr (MatrixType::MaxRowsAtCompileTime == 1 || 
                MatrixType::MaxColsAtCompileTime ==1 ||
               (MatrixType::Options&Eigen::RowMajor) == Eigen::RowMajor) {
    std::copy(matrix.data(), matrix.data() + matrix.size(), data.begin());
    return data;
  } else {
    Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, Cols, Eigen::RowMajor, MaxRows, MaxCols> tmp = matrix;
    return write(tmp);
  }
}
```

**2. SFINAE**

You can dispatch the call to `write` at compile-time using SFINAE by using `std::enable_if`. The following example uses a slightly modified version of your original code but everything should be clear from context:

```
// matrix is either a vector or in row-major
template <typename Derived>
std::vector<typename Derived::Scalar> write(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix,
  typename std::enable_if<Derived::MaxRowsAtCompileTime == 1 ||
                          Derived::MaxColsAtCompileTime == 1 ||
                          (Derived::Options & Eigen::RowMajor) == Eigen::RowMajor,
                          Derived>::type* = 0)
{
  std::vector<typename Derived::Scalar> data(
      static_cast<size_t>(matrix.size()));
  std::copy(matrix.derived().data(), matrix.derived().data() + matrix.size(),
            data.begin());
  return data;
}

// matrix is neither a vector nor in row-major
template <typename Derived>
std::vector<typename Derived::Scalar> write(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix,
  typename std::enable_if<Derived::MaxRowsAtCompileTime != 1 &&
                          Derived::MaxColsAtCompileTime != 1 &&
                          (Derived::Options & Eigen::RowMajor) == 0,
                          Derived>::type* = 0)
{
  Eigen::Matrix<typename Derived::Scalar, Derived::RowsAtCompileTime,
                Derived::ColsAtCompileTime, Eigen::RowMajor,
                Derived::MaxRowsAtCompileTime, Derived::MaxColsAtCompileTime> tmp = matrix;
  return write(tmp);
}
```

This works using a C++11 compiler.

Other options would be to specialise the template but it will get even more lengthy than the SFINAE approach.

Some test cases:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> m;
m << 1, 2, 3, 
     1, 2, 3,
     1, 2, 3;

std::vector<int> output = write(m);

for (const auto& element : output) {
  std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

> Output: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, 3, 3, Eigen::ColMajor> m;
m << 1, 2, 3, 
     1, 2, 3,
     1, 2, 3;

std::vector<int> output = write(m);

for (const auto& element : output) {
  std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

> Output: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

```
Eigen::VectorXi m = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(10, 0, 9);

std::vector<int> output = write(m);

for (const auto& element : output) {
  std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

> Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

```
Eigen::RowVectorXi m = Eigen::RowVectorXi::LinSpaced(10, 0, 9);

std::vector<int> output = write(m);

for (const auto& element : output) {
  std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

> Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Am I write about my assertion there is no way of doing this without the copy?

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird, your code is still statically assertion for me, with same message as before (with `Eigen::VectorXi`). Most weird is that when I replace the code under `else` for a `throw` I find that actually the first case is being selected.

Comment: @TomdeGeus could your specify your Compiler version and the C++ standard you are using?

Comment: Yes: `clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.7/include/eigen3 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test test.cpp`. `clang++ --version` gives `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)`

Comment: Ups, thats totally my fault! Each conditional branch has to be correct since this is a static assertion, sorry for that! I will update in some minutes.

Comment: @TomdeGeus Please consider the update. To answer your other question: It is possible to avoid the copy (and I would recommend to do so) by walking through `data` manually. Open a new question (and maybe link it here) and I will try to find some time to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution is to let `Eigen::Ref` does all the job for you:

```
Ref<const Matrix<T,Rows,Cols,Cols==1?ColMajor:RowMajor,MaxRows,MaxCols>,0, InnerStride<1> > row_maj(matrix);
```

Then `row_maj` will be guaranteed to be sequentially stored in row-major order. If `matrix` is compatible, then no copy occurs. No branch, no SFINAE, etc.

Here `matrix` can be any expression, not only a `Matrix<...>` but also sub-matrices, `Map`, another `Ref`, etc.

To handle any expressions, just replace `Rows` and the likes with `XprType::RowsAtCompileTime` where `XprType` is the type of `matrix`.

```
template <class XprType>
std::vector<typename XprType::Scalar> write(const Eigen::MatrixBase<XprType>& matrix)
{...}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed, cleaner and simpler!